# RegEx: метасимвол перевода строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регулярным выражением

Исходный текст

```
test4

<hr>test1
test2
<hr>

:test3
```

Выходной (желаемый) текст

```
test4abc:test3
```

Регулярное выражение, которое я пробовал

```
/<hr>(.*?)<hr>/s
```

Как мне "удалить" все метасимволы перевода строки, табуляции и пробелов (т.е. невидимых символов) до и после этого текста?
Заранее спасибо!

ОТВЕТ:

```
/([\W])([\n\r]*)<hr>(.*?)<hr>([\n\r]*)([\W])/us
```

Comment: зачем вам это? мне крайне трудно придумать реальное назначение для этого. по моему вы решаете не ту задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
/\s*<hr>(.*?)<hr>\s*/s
```

Comment: ни один не сработал

Comment: Почему не сработало?  Возможно Вы что-то делали не так:  

    $RE0="/\\s*+<hr>(.*?)<hr>\\s*+/s";
    $text= <<<hereof
    
    test4
    
    <hr>test1
    test2
    <hr>
    
    :test3
    hereof;
    $t= preg_replace($RE0, "abc", $text); // test4abc:test3

Comment: спасибо, так действительно работает!

Answer (score 0):

\r\n возврат каретки и перевод строки

Comment: Есть вариант, ([\W])([\n\r]*)<hr>(.*?)<hr>([\r\n]*)([\W]), но при таком варианте проблема с русскими буквами...